# Как расчитать координаты x, y для перемещения курсора в 3д

Tags: python, математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При помощи opencv знаю координаты (x1, y1) объекта, знаю FOV, а сама игра находится в 3д пространстве и просто передавая координаты получится переместить прицел куда то около (x2, y2), каким образом возможно рассчитать нужные координаты x1, y1? Догадываюсь что это делается с помощью FOV, но не понимаю до конца как это сделать. Заранее благодарю =)

Comment: Вопрос слишком абстрактный

Comment: надеюсь поправил и так понятнее

Comment: Курсор то у вас на плоскости находится. openCV вам выдаёт 2 координаты, вам нужно просто кликнуть в середину между этих координат `x1 + w / 2 ` где w - ширина монитора, с высотой всё точно так же.

Comment: Ууупсидейзи - w - ширина шаблона OpenCV

Comment: Это не сработает, т.к для opencv изображение лежит на плоскости x, y  , А игра находится в x, y, z плоскости, из за этого нельзя таким образом переместить курсор в координаты x1, y1. и x1, y1 = середина цели

Comment: Да не важно в какой плоскости у вас находится игра - OpenCV использует координаты изображения, а у изображения две плоскости X, Y. Дисплей у вас тоже плоский, с координатами X и Y. Высчитайте центр найденного обьекта, переместите курсор и кликните туда.

Comment: У Хауди Хо™ что то похожее видел https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJbvPGCqW8s

Comment: @PeFoo, а, теперь понятно, что ты имел ввиду. 3д игры не обязательно от первого лица. При движении курсора меняется положение объекта, это уже другое дело, извиняюсь.

Comment: да сколько можно уже объяснять что это так не работает, чем дальше находится цель от прицела, тем больше погрешность в координате x1, y1. 2d != 3d, при перемещении прицела, просто даже смоделируйте в голове пройденную дистанцию до координаты x1, y1 в плоскости x, y и дистанция в x, y, z. При движении в x, y, z мы двигаем прицел, а не персонажа.

Comment: @СергейШ да вы правы, я это уже видел, но то насколько сильно много написано для этого расчёта меня смутило, поэтому решил полезть на форумы =)

Comment: Тем более у хауди слишком узко направленно получилось